# Flash video streaming - seek to frame & slow/fast-motion

Tags: video-streaming, flv, rtmp, flvplayback, streaming-flv-video

I am working on a project where an FLV is streamed to a player - the player needs to be able to seek to exact frame numbers and pause on them.

The end goal is to achieve a variable playing speed - the player will go to a frame, pause, then go to the next frame, pause, and so forth.  (it can also go to previous frames, if rewind is requested) - only for a part of the movie (e.g. when the user selects "slow-mo").

Currently, RTMP is used to serve the flash video content.

1. Is it possible to seek to any frame with flash video files, or only key-frames?
2. Is it possible to request a portion of a movie via RTMP - and break down the content into frames locally and store an image-per-frame in memory, overlaying the video window and displaying content frame-by-frame?

Any advice on the above will be appreciated!

Arkadi

Comment: is there a similar question which answers this ?

Comment: if the video is embedded on the time line this level of frame control is easily possible.
even i would like to know if this level of frame control is possible without the use of cue points or such.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to seek only on key-frames.
Adobe FMS has builtin transcoder that makes possible to decode frames inside GOP and make frame-precise seeking, but it is not a good idea because of very high server load with bad results.

So easier to do it on flash player with enabled access to video samples.